# How do I mount debugfs?

Tags: mount, amd-graphics

I'm having issues playing TF2 due to random hangs. According to this git, https://github.com/ValveSoftware/Source-1-Games/issues/1943 the issue is clunky Mesa dynamic power management. I've tried to resolve this by installing Radeon Profile from this repository https://launchpad.net/~trebelnik-stefina/+archive/ubuntu/radeon-profile so I can force high performance mode while I play, but unfortunately the application says [image]
How does one mount debugfs? I've read that

> mount -t debugfs none /sys/kernel/debug/

is the best command to use, but this gives me

> mount: none is already mounted or /sys/kernel/debug busy

in terminal. I'm not at all familiar with mounting things other than CDs so any help is greatly appreciated. Alternate ways to interact with dpm would also be great. Thanks!